# Calling a function from both the main and the renderer process in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a function that I call from both the main process and from the renderer process. It accesses a global. Is there an idiomatic way of coding this in Electron, or should I just do something like this:

```
function f() {
   const { remote } = require("electron").remote;
   if (remote) {
      return remote.getGlobal("abc");
   }

   return global.abc;
}
```